# how to combine different rows's text in a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to combine different row's values in table in oracle. For example, consider this table

[image]

I want the output as

```
HI TOM,    
ITS COLD,
PL- SQL
```

As you see the columns are combined on QID and separated by space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like

```
SELECT qid, wmsys.wm_concat(answer) CONCAT 
FROM t
GROUP BY qid;
```

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that you get `HI TOM` or `TOM HI`. You should add/use another column to keep the order in the result rows stable.

Comment: Without ordering, this is no solution.

Comment: here the values are separated by comma in wm_concat, how can i use '\n' ie line break.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you are on 11g2 you can use listagg function, it also allows ordering :

```
SELECT qid, listagg(answer,' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ROWNUM) 
  FROM t
 GROUP BY qid
```

Finally, if you are not on 11g2 and you dont have wm_contact function as suggested by [@steve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209131/how-to-combine-different-rowss-text-in-a-table-in-oracle/8209229#8209229), you could use the following :

```
SELECT qid,
       rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, answer || ' ')).extract('//text()'), ' ') 
  FROM t
 GROUP BY qid
```